# Is it possible to make text centered in richtextbox C#

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I was wondering if is possible to make text in richtextbox centered?
Right now text is in top left corner and I want to make it centered in the middle.
As far I don't see any properties to do that.

Comment: First off, you should indicate if this is WinForms, WPF or what exactly. Second, does the text need to be edited? Or are you just displaying it?

Comment: If it is WPF check VerticalAlignment and HorizontalAlignment